# custom api endpoint for newsletter unsubscription question

Tags: api, magento2.4.6, newsletter-subscriber

I wrote an API endpoint to handle unsubscribe thru API call
It is working well. However, I don't want Magento to send out unsubscribe email to customer, how can I achieve this?

Thanks

```
<?php

namespace ABC\NewsletterEndpoint\Model;

use ABC\NewsletterEndpoint\Api\SubscriptionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;

class Subscription implements SubscriptionInterface
{
    protected $subscriberFactory;
    protected $customer;
    protected $storemanager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Newsletter\Model\SubscriberFactory $subscriberFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customer,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storemanager
    ) {
        $this->subscriberFactory = $subscriberFactory;
        $this->customer = $customer;
        $this->storemanager = $storemanager;
    }

    /**
     * Returns user email
     * @param string $email
     * @return void
     */
    public function subscribeByEmail($email)
    {
        $websiteId = $this->storemanager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
        $customerId = $this->customer->create()->setWebsiteId($websiteId)->loadByEmail($email)->getId();
        if ($customerId) {
            $this->subscriberFactory->create()->subscribeCustomerById($customerId);
        } else {
            $this->subscriberFactory->create()->subscribe($email);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param string $email
     * @return string
     */
    public function isSubscribed($email)
    {
        $subscriber = $this->subscriberFactory->create()->loadByEmail($email);
        if ($subscriber->getId()) {
            if ($subscriber->isSubscribed()) {
                return "Email found. Subscription status: Subscribed";
            } else {
                return "Email found. Subscription status: Not Subscribed";
            }
        } else {
            throw new NoSuchEntityException(__('Email not found'));
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param string $email
     * @return void
     */
    public function deleteByEmail($email)
    {
        $websiteId = $this->storemanager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
        $customerId = $this->customer->create()->setWebsiteId($websiteId)->loadByEmail($email)->getId();

        // Check if the email belongs to a customer
        if ($customerId) {
            $this->subscriberFactory->create()->unsubscribeCustomerById($customerId, true); // Disable email sending
            return; // Unsubscribed successfully
        }

        // Check if the email exists in the newsletter subscriber table
        $subscriber = $this->subscriberFactory->create()->loadByEmail($email);
        if ($subscriber->getId()) {
            $subscriber->unsubscribe(true); // Disable email sending
            return; // Unsubscribed successfully
        }

        // If email is neither a customer nor a newsletter subscriber, do nothing
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the functionality in vendor/magento/module-newsletter/Model/Subscriber.php class.

```
/**
 * Unsubscribes loaded subscription
 *
 * @throws LocalizedException
 * @return $this
 */
public function unsubscribe()
{
    if ($this->hasCheckCode() && $this->getCode() != $this->getCheckCode()) {
        throw new LocalizedException(
            __('This is an invalid subscription confirmation code.')
        );
    }

    if ($this->getSubscriberStatus() != self::STATUS_UNSUBSCRIBED) {
        $this->setStatus(self::STATUS_UNSUBSCRIBED);
        $this->save();
        $this->sendUnsubscriptionEmail();
    }
    return $this;
}
```

You need to remove the following line from the above code snippet:

```
$this->sendUnsubscriptionEmail();
```

You can pluginize or overwrite the above class method.

Comment: Thanks Sohel. I just want this happen, when people unsubscribe thru API call. So Magento won't send out unsubscription email. But if people unsubscribe thru Magento, the system will still send out unscubscription email. If I using the plugin method, this will only happen for API calls only? It won't completely overwrite the default functionality?

Comment: This is a common method, so it will block email from FE functionality. You need to send some flags from API and add logic in the above method.

Answer (score 0):

I finally manage to modify this function by Import mode

```
   public function deleteByEmail($email)
{

    // Check if the email exists in the newsletter subscriber table
    $subscriber = $this->subscriberFactory->create()->loadByEmail($email);
    if ($subscriber->getId()) {
        // If the email exists in the newsletter subscriber table, unsubscribe the subscriber
        // Disable email sending by setting the subscriber into "import mode"
        $subscriber->setImportMode(true);
        $subscriber->unsubscribe();
        $subscriber->save();
        return; // Unsubscribed successfully
    }

    // If email is neither a customer nor a newsletter subscriber, do nothing
}
```